# Simple calculating question

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

in a proof I was reading it was all reduced to $$ \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^k \leq \left(\frac{n-k}{n-k-1}\right)^{n-k-1}.$$ It is given that $k < \frac{n}{2}$. (It might also be quite helpful that from this $k+1 \leq n-k$ follows).

Somehow I always come to a dead end in proving this.

It would be very nice if you could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The theorem says $\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k\leq\left(1+\frac1{n-k-1}\right)^{n-k-1}$ so you want to look at the function $\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$

Comment: I did, can you please give me one more hint (I know that it is increasing but I don't see how this helps)

Comment: You've shown that $k\leq n-k-1$, so if you've shown that the function is increasing, you're done.

Comment: Oh, now I see it!
Thank you very much

Comment: It was my pleasure.